# htaccess Rewrite - completely different path

Tags: .htaccess

I have the follwing htaccess Rewrite Problem:

I have a domain like www.example.org and the files are in /var/www/www.example.org/

Now I need a rewrite for every Site in www.example.org/b/w/ to /var/www/www.anothersite.org/b/w/
I dont know exactly how I can do this, is this possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does this mean? "Now I need a rewrite for every Site in www.example.org/b/w/ to /var/www/www.anothersite.org/b/w/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite outside of your document root, but you can redirect (it will change the URL in the browser's address bar):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?b/w/(.*)$ http://www.anothersite.org/b/w/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /b/w/ http://www.anothersite.org/b/w/
```

If you need the address bar to stay the same, you can use mod_proxy if that's enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?b/w/(.*)$ http://www.anothersite.org/b/w/$1 [P,L]
```

Or if you have access to the server or vhost config, just create an alias:

```
Alias /b/w/ /var/www/www.anothersite.org/b/w/
```

Or worst case, just symlink `/var/www/www.example.org/b/w/` to `/var/www/www.anothersite.org/b/w/`

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin
I didn't thought on Aliases in vhost.
This solves the problem really easy :D

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^b/([w]+) http://www.anothersite.org/b/w/$1 [L,NC]
```

That should do it :)

Comment: but is there any way to do this without the http//www.anothersite.org?

Comment: because I have no access to the DNS and it should only rewrite it on the local server

Comment: With .htaccess redirects, the second parameter needs to be the full URL you are redirecting to, starting with `http://`

Comment: @Evil_skunk you won't need access to the DNS, it'll just send the visitor from `www.example.org/b/w/` to `www.anothersite.org/b/w/`

Comment: thanks for your help, but www.anothersite.org doesnt really exists, so I cant redirect to it...
Jon Lin's answer works perfekt for me

Comment: @Evil_skunk Ah, I see now, it was just another folder on the server - yes, the alias solution is your best bet in that case. Please don't forget to accept his answer!